# Constant expression works when is done as parts but not as a single function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

The code works for a,b,A,W, but fails for J.
It is the exact same code just broken apart.
What gives?

I am trying to get "make" work as a constant expression.
The code is not that complex for the compiler to fail on this simple example.

Very strange...

```
template<typename... Args> constexpr
auto all2(Args... args) noexcept
{ return static_cast<int>((... + args)); }

struct xx
{
    int y = 2;
    constexpr operator int () const noexcept { return y; }
};

template<int C, typename... Args>
struct pepe2
{
    constexpr pepe2( Args... args ){}
};

template< typename... T_ARGS > constexpr
auto make( const T_ARGS&... args ) noexcept
{
    return pepe2< all2(args...), T_ARGS... >{};
}

int main()
{
    // This works as expected
    constexpr static xx             a   {};
    constexpr static xx             b   {};
    constexpr static auto           A   { all2( a, b ) };
    constexpr static pepe2<A,xx,xx> W   { a, b };

    // But this does not!!!
    constexpr static auto  J    = make( a, b );

    return 0;
}
```

---

### Actual Errors from Clang

```
<source>:21:24: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression

    return pepe2< all2(args...), T_ARGS... >{};

                       ^

<source>:33:35: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'make<xx, xx>' requested here

    constexpr static auto  J    = make( a, b );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function parameter are not constant expressions. You can pass `a` and `b` as template parameters instead.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename... Args> constexpr
auto all2(Args... args) noexcept
{ return static_cast<int>((... + args)); }

struct xx
{
    int y = 2;
    constexpr operator int () const noexcept { return y; }
};

template<int C, typename... Args>
struct pepe2
{
    constexpr pepe2( Args... ){}
};

template< auto&... T_ARGS > constexpr
auto make() noexcept
{
    return pepe2< all2(T_ARGS...), std::decay_t<decltype(T_ARGS)>... >{T_ARGS...};
}

int main()
{
    // This works as expected
    constexpr static xx             a   {};
    constexpr static xx             b   {};
    constexpr static auto           A   { all2( a, b ) };
    constexpr static pepe2<A,xx,xx> W   { a, b };

    // This also works now
    constexpr static auto  J    = make<a, b>();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Function arguments are not `constexpr`. Indeed, `make` function could take non-costexpr arguments. So, we cannot use them for templates instantiation.